# Check several field to execute switch case

Tags: php, loops, switch-statement

I have a code to check through several fields to execute certain code as below:

```
switch($tag1 || $tag2 || $tag3 || $tag4 ||$tag5){
            case "satay":
            $imgput = "/home/uploads/sandbox/jovine/Food/tags/satay/$img_name";
            break;

            case "digitalmarketing":
            $imgput = "/home/uploads/sandbox/jovine/Food/tags/interactive_marketing/$img_name";
            break;
            case "chillicrab":
            $imgput = "/home/uploads/sandbox/jovine/Food/tags/chilli_crab/$img_name";
            break;
            case "chickenrice":
            $imgput = "/home/uploads/sandbox/jovine/Food/tags/chicken_rice/$img_name";
            break;
            case "chendol":
            $imgput = "/home/uploads/sandbox/jovine/Food/tags/chendol/$img_name";
            break;
            }
```

But it does not work.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Are you expecting it to output the case for "Satay" if any of the `$tag1...5` variables contain `satay`?

Comment: Yes!I mean that but it does not work is there any  problem with this : switch($tag1 || $tag2 || $tag3 || $tag4 ||$tag5) ??

Comment: sometimes all you need is to check the manual before ask -> http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: I am not certain, but I am pretty sure that a switch statement can only be applied to one variable at a time. Let me see if I can put a structure together that will do what you need however.

Comment: this is not the only way just use an if else?

Comment: @youaremysunshine Posted a nice short bit of code that should hopefully be the simlest way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Switch` support one value only. Only `IF` condition can have `OR` and `AND` condition.

```
$tags = get the tag value.
    switch($tags){
                case "satay":
                $imgput = "/home/uploads/sandbox/jovine/Food/tags/satay/$img_name";
                break;

                case "digitalmarketing":
                $imgput = "/home/uploads/sandbox/jovine/Food/tags/interactive_marketing/$img_name";
                break;
                case "chillicrab":
                $imgput = "/home/uploads/sandbox/jovine/Food/tags/chilli_crab/$img_name";
                break;
                case "chickenrice":
                $imgput = "/home/uploads/sandbox/jovine/Food/tags/chicken_rice/$img_name";
                break;
                case "chendol":
                $imgput = "/home/uploads/sandbox/jovine/Food/tags/chendol/$img_name";
                break;
                }
```

Comment: and I know your from Malaysia. Satay is my favourite,, :)

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick for you:

```
<?php

    $tag1='satay';
    $tag2='test2';
    $tag3='digitalmarketing';

    function isItThere($myTag)
    {
        switch($myTag)
        {
            case "satay":
                $imgput = "/home/uploads/sandbox/jovine/Food/tags/satay/$img_name";
                echo $imgput;
                break;
            case "digitalmarketing":
                $imgput = "/home/uploads/sandbox/jovine/Food/tags/interactive_marketing/$img_name";
                echo $imgput;
                break;
            // etc etc
        }
    }


    for($i=1;$i<4;$i++)
    {
        isItThere(${'tag'.$i});
    }

?>
```

I have basically set up a small function that contains the switch statement and written a simple loop to test the variables.

As I said in my comment, you can't use more than one variable in the switch statement, but this will provide you a nice clean workaround to do the same thing without the need to write many long statements.